# How to trace the Website visitor Count?

Tags: asp.net

I need to implement the website visitor count Usercontrol.Can any one help me regarding this in .Net?

Comment: you can go through this link http://www.website-hit-counters.com/signup.php?style=bullet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In global.asax, do this:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code, der beim Starten der Anwendung ausgeführt wird.
    ' Set our user count to 0 when we start the server 
    Application("ActiveUsers") = 0
End Sub


Sub Application_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code, der beim Beenden der Anwendung ausgeführt wird.
    Application("ActiveUsers") = 0
End Sub



Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code, der beim Starten einer neuen Sitzung ausgeführt wird.
    Session.Timeout = 20
    Session("Start") = Now
    Application.Lock()
    Application("ActiveUsers") = CInt(Application("ActiveUsers")) + 1
    Application.UnLock()
End Sub


Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code, der am Ende einer Sitzung ausgeführt wird. 
    ' Hinweis: Das Session_End-Ereignis wird nur ausgelöst, wenn der sessionstate-Modus
    ' in der Datei "Web.config" auf InProc festgelegt wird. Wenn der Sitzungsmodus auf StateServer 
    ' oder SQLServer festgelegt wird, wird das Ereignis nicht ausgelöst.
    Application.Lock()
    Application("ActiveUsers") = CInt(Application("ActiveUsers")) - 1
    Application.UnLock()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using (or creating) a global.asax file.

Every time a session is started, you increment an integer, which holds the number of current visitors. Every time a session is ended, you subtract one from that integer. Next, you will have to use public properties for all pages to be able to retrieve the information.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private static int totalNumberOfUsers = 0;
    private static int currentNumberOfUsers = 0;

    protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      totalNumberOfUsers += 1;
      currentNumberOfUsers += 1;
    }
    protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      currentNumberOfUsers -= 1;
    }
    protected void Application_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    public static int TotalNumberOfUsers{ get { return totalNumberOfUsers; } } 
    public static int CurrentNumberOfUsers{ get { return currentNumberOfUsers; } } 
}
```

Next, in your control, set the values of the global.asax file in the right labels.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  int currentNumberOfUsers = HitCounters.Global.CurrentNumberOfUsers;
  int totalNumberOfUsers = HitCounters.Global.TotalNumberOfUsers;
  lblCurrentNumberOfUsers.Text = currentNumberOfUsers.ToString();
  lblTotalNumberOfUsers.Text = totalNumberOfUsers.ToString();
}
```